# Perl one liner inside a perl script not working

Tags: perl

my text file contents

```
vi /root/text.conf

node.session.auth.authmethod = hello
```

so my one liner perl command replaces the above file contents by commenting with #. Works fine when run as single command

```
perl -pi -e 's/^(node.session.auth.authmethod\s*=\s*).*$/#\1hello/g' /root/text.conf
```

when the perl one liner code is executed inside  perl script, it does not comment out the text.conf file contents.

```
$cmd ="perl -pi -e 's/^(node.session.auth.authmethod\s*=\s*).*$/#\1hello/g' /root/text.conf"

$line = `$cmd 2>&1`;$ret = $?;
```

Am I missing something while executing Perl one liner inside a Perl script.

Comment: Don't do that. It's very nasty to matrioshka your scripts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, use current perl process instead of forking new one. This is equivalent of your

```
perl -pi -e 's/^(node.session.auth.authmethod\s*=\s*).*$/#\1hello/g' /root/text.conf
```

one-liner,

```
use strict;
use warnings;

local $^I = "";
local @ARGV = "/root/text.conf";

while (<>) { 
  s/^(node.session.auth.authmethod\s*=\s*).*$/#\1hello/g;
  print;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Defining your `$cmd` the Variable `$/` will be replaced by it's value (the line separator). Then the regex will not match your line.

Try using single quotes (along with proper escaping):

```
$cmd ='perl -pi -e \'s/^(node.session.auth.authmethod\s*=\s*).*$/#\1hello/g\' /root/text.conf'

$line = `$cmd 2>&1`;$ret = $?;
```

This will prevent perl from expanding variables.

Nevertheless mpapec's answer is right, why forking a new process?